# Discussing the definition of continuity of linear functionals on the space $\mathcal{D} (\mathbb{R}^{n})$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, vector-spaces, continuity

$\mathcal{D} (\mathbb{R}^{n})$ the vector space over the field $\mathbb{C}$ such that its elements are "nice" functions $\varphi :\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. We say that a function is "nice" if:

1. It's smooth
2. It has compact support

This is what I've studied.

The functional $F_{f} [\varphi]$ is continuous in the following sense: Consider a sequence of functions $\{ \varphi_{k}(x) \}$ in $\mathcal{D} (\mathbb{R}^{n})$ with the following two properties:

1. There exists a compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that for all $k$, $\mbox{supp}\ \varphi_{k} \subset K$.
2. $\lim_{k \to \infty} \partial^{m}\varphi_{k}(x) = 0$ uniformly for all $m = 0, 1, 2, \cdots$.

Such a sequence is said to go to $0$ in $\mathcal{D}$ and is written $\varphi_{k} \to 0, \ k \to \infty$ in $\mathcal{D}$.

We then say that the functional $F_{f}[\varphi]$ is continuous if $F_{f}[\varphi_{k}] \to 0$ for $\varphi_{k} \to 0, \ k \to \infty$ in $\mathcal{D}$.

Continuity is a topological property. The space $\mathcal{D}$ is a linear vector space. It is made into a topological vector space by defining the neighbourhood of the “point” $\varphi (x) = 0$ by a sequence of semi-norms.

I've read that the two conditions required above in the definition of $\varphi_{k} \to 0$ in $\mathcal{D}$ follow from the conditions used to define the neighbourhood of $\varphi(x) = 0$. Why is this true though?

Comment: How are the seminorms defined?